# windowIsTranslucent set to true, exitAnim does not work

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, activity-transition

I'm trying to make custom transition animations when opening a new activity using:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.zoom_in, R.anim.go_out);
```

The new activity has the following theme:

```
<style name="Modal" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

I discovered that the property that makes exitAnim not work is "windowIsTranslucent" set to true. If I comment that line out , then my "go_out" exit animation works just fine.

Any solution for this problem?

Comment: Did you find any workaround?

Comment: I didn't unfortunately. Couldn't find anything so I ended up removing "windowIsTranslucent" in activities with custom exit animations. If you find anything, please let me know!